# Autocompletebox doesn't clear keyboard strokes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

In an application of mine, I'm using the WPF autocomplete box from the wpf toolkit. I'm implementing it via the MVVM pattern. The binding works fine, but I have a small problem when trying to clear the content of the autocompletebox. Setting the bound property in the viewmodel to null, clears the text only partially (all text entered via the keyboard is not cleared - i.e. if I enter CH when fetching all the cities and select Chicago and the set the bound property to null, the CH is not being cleared , the rest ICAGO is.)

The XAML looks like this:

```
           <my:AutoCompleteBox Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="1" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                Margin="0,6,0,0" 
                                Name="acTown" 
                                SelectedItem="{Binding NewTown, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TownConverter}}"        
                                Populating="Populating"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                Height="Auto" 
            </my:AutoCompleteBox>
```

The method in the viewmodel to clear the box is:

```
   public void ClearTown()
    {

    NewTown = null;

    OnPropertyChanged("NewTown");
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with the code, or is this just a bug in the autocompletebox?

After extensive research, I found this article: [How do you clear the Silverlight AutoCompleteBox SearchText using MVVM](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/clear-silverlight-autocompletebox-212381.aspx), but it does not offer a solution. There seems to be a SearchText property on the AutoCompleteBox that is readonly and cannot have a setter

Comment: How about clearing the Text property of the AutoCompleteBox too?

Comment: @SoMoS How do I clear the Text property of the AutoCompleteBox using the MVVM pattern?

Comment: Binding it to a property of the VM and clearing it when needed.

Comment: Tried this but the end result is the same. The input entered via keyboard doesn't get cleared. If you read the article I referenced above, there seems to be a SearchText property that is readonly (private) to the AutoCompleteBox that holds the user input. I don't know how to clear this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it. If anyone's interested, the solution is to simply change `NewTown = null` to `NewTown = new NewTown()` in the ClearTown function.

Comment: This solved the issue of clearing the textbox for me. It's a hack but it works! Watch out for code depending on the ``SelectedItem`` being null, as I was in a related button command which was enabling/disabling based on what was in the ``SelectedItem``property. Might be worth introducing something like the Null Object pattern, where you assign the ``SelectedItem`` a ``Town.NullTown`` object, which can be checked for later.